# Getting string out of recursive_directory_iterator

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm trying to use C++17's `<experimental/filesystem>` to get all the filenames out of a directory and fill a `vector<string>` with them.

I know how to print them out like this:

```
void ShaderManager::LoadFilenames(std::string path)
{
    for (auto& p : fs::recursive_directory_iterator(path))
    {
        std::cout << p << '\n';
    }
}
```

But if I try, `m_ShaderFileNames.push_back(p.path().filename);` inside the for loop then I get *'std::experimental::filesystem::v1::path::filename': non-standard syntax; use '&'*. But if I try that then I get *illegal operation on bound member function expression*.

**Edit**: I've tried `m_ShaderFileNames.push_back(p.path().filename())` too but that one throws: *no instance of overloaded function "std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::push_back [with _Ty=std::string, _Alloc=std::allocator]" matches the argument list*

There is probably a very simple solution but I can't seem to find it!

Comment: Just nitpicking, but in C++17 it's no longer experimental, but fully integrated as [`std::filesystem`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem).

Comment: As for your problem, please try to create a [mcve] to show us. And please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: I think you mean to call the `filename()` function. When you write it as `p.path().filename` you're referring to the function itself as an object, not calling it.

Comment: Lastly a ***guess*** about your problem: [`filename`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/filename) is a *function* that you need to *call*.

Comment: One more suggestion: if a string is a path, *just use `path`*; that's what it is for. Only turn a `path` into a string if you are going to pass it to an API that treats it as a general string (printing, storing in a file, etc). Keep it as a `path` within your application for as long as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
m_ShaderFileNames.push_back(p.path().filename().string());
```

If `p` is `recursive_directory_iterator`, then `path()` returns [`filesystem::path`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path), so it has a method [`filename`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/filename) which returns the filename component of the path. Then you can call the [`string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/string) method to get the path as a string.

Comment: I think there might have to be an additional conversion involved as it now throws *no instance of overloaded function "std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::push_back [with _Ty=std::string, _Alloc=std::allocator<std::string>]" matches the argument list*

Comment: @DLPDev ciorect, edited